# Why can't Z3 prove/admit that `is_int` is closed under some operations?

Tags: z3, smt, theorem-proving

For example, the following query times out:

```
(declare-const x Real)
(declare-const y Real)
(assert (is_int x))
(assert (is_int y))
(assert (not (is_int (+ x y))))
(check-sat)
```

As far as I've read, Z3's `Real` are mathematical reals and not machine ones with subtle semantics. Is there any problem in admitting that some operations preserve `is_int`?

Answer (score 1):

Z3 reduces this to solving a mixed-integer linear problem, which is one of the weaker areas. It ends up producing endless branch and cuts in this case.